# Efficient concatenation ignoring suffixes in index

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I do have two dataframes like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"c1": range(5), "c2": range(1, 6)}, index=list("ABCDE"))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"c3": range(15, 21), "c4": range(11, 17)}, index=["A_suf1", "B_suf2", "A_suf2", "C_suf2", "B_suf1", "D_suf1"])   

   c1  c2    
A   0   1
B   1   2
C   2   3
D   3   4
E   4   5

        c3  c4
A_suf1  15  11
B_suf2  16  12
A_suf2  17  13
C_suf2  18  14
B_suf1  19  15
D_suf1  20  16
```

which I want to turn into

```
       c3  c4  c1
A_suf1  15  11   0
B_suf2  16  12   1
A_suf2  17  13   0
C_suf2  18  14   2
B_suf1  19  15   1
D_suf1  20  16   3
```

So, I want to concatenate the dataframes independent of the suffixes `suf1` and `suf2` in the index of `df2`. As the entry in `c1` in `df1` for column `A` is 0, it should then appear in the concatenated dataframe for the entries `A_suf1` and `A_suf2`.

I currently implement this as follows:

```
# store original name of index
old_index = df2.index
# temporary column which creates values which are in the the index of df1
df2['helper'] = df2.reset_index()["index"].apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[0]).tolist()
# prepare concat
df2 = df2.set_index("helper")
# concat
df_final = pd.concat([df2, df1.loc[:, "c1"]], join="inner", axis=1)
# reset index to original values
df_final.index = old_index
```

which gives me the desired output.

However, it requires a rather slow `apply` and it will also fail if there is an index entry in `df2` which is not in `df1`. For example, the above code will fail for `df2` equals

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"c3": range(15, 22), "c4": range(11, 18)}, index=["A_suf1", "B_suf2", "A_suf2", "C_suf2", "B_suf1", "D_suf1", "F_suf1"])

        c3  c4
A_suf1  15  11
B_suf2  16  12
A_suf2  17  13
C_suf2  18  14
B_suf1  19  15
D_suf1  20  16
F_suf1  21  17
```

Question is therefore whether there is a more efficient and general solution out there for the working and also non-working case, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) by `MultiIndex` created splitted `index` of `df2` with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for `Multiindex` of `df1`:

```
df2.index = df2.index.str.split('_', expand=True)
print(df2)
        c3  c4
A suf1  15  11
B suf2  16  12
A suf2  17  13
C suf2  18  14
B suf1  19  15
D suf1  20  16

print (df1['c1'].reindex(df2.index,level=0))
A  suf1    0
B  suf2    1
A  suf2    0
C  suf2    2
B  suf1    1
D  suf1    3
Name: c1, dtype: int32

df = df2.join(df1['c1'].reindex(df2.index,level=0))
#convert MultiIndex to index
df.index = df.index.map('_'.join)
print (df)
        c3  c4  c1
A_suf1  15  11   0
B_suf2  16  12   1
A_suf2  17  13   0
C_suf2  18  14   2
B_suf1  19  15   1
D_suf1  20  16   3
```

For another `df2` get:

```
print (df)
        c3  c4   c1
A_suf1  15  11  0.0
B_suf2  16  12  1.0
A_suf2  17  13  0.0
C_suf2  18  14  2.0
B_suf1  19  15  1.0
D_suf1  20  16  3.0
F_suf1  21  17  NaN
```

Comment: Very nice (upvoted)! Seems to solve both of my problems efficiently.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Yes, it is another solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to convert to a `MultiIndex`. You can just extract the indices and use `df.loc` with `pd.concat` to join.

```
idx = [x[0] for x in df2.index]
out = pd.concat([df2, df1.loc[idx, ['c1']].set_index(df2.index)], 1)
print(out)
        c3  c4  c1
A_suf1  15  11   0
B_suf2  16  12   1
A_suf2  17  13   0
C_suf2  18  14   2
B_suf1  19  15   1
D_suf1  20  16   3
```

For your second dataframe, I get

```
        c3  c4   c1
A_suf1  15  11  0.0
B_suf2  16  12  1.0
A_suf2  17  13  0.0
C_suf2  18  14  2.0
B_suf1  19  15  1.0
D_suf1  20  16  3.0
F_suf1  21  17  NaN
```

---

**Performance**

## Small

```
# converting to MultiIndex
100 loops, best of 3: 3.57 ms per loop

# using `df.loc` and `df.set_index`
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work fine, too (upvoted); still need to figure out why the `split` doe snot appear anywhere though. ;)